# Pynput only works in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pynput

I'm making a Tetris clone that runs in terminal and I'm using the Pynput Keyboard Listener to listen for user input. Everything works fine when I run it in Pycharm (be it by pressing the "run" button or when I launch it with `$ python3 main.py` from Pycharm's built-in terminal. However, when I open a "standalone" terminal and launch the program inside it, the Listener doesn't do anything, even though it seems to be running when I run `for thread in threading.enumerate(): print(thread.name)` in the script (same output in both terminals).

Pycharm is using the default Python interpreter (`/usr/bin/python3.8`). Running `pip list` returns the same information when run in both terminals. Running the program as root doesn't change the behaviour in either terminal. Neither does running it with the absolute path of the interpreter, `$ /usr/bin/python3.8 main.py`.

I have tried `$ pip install --force-reinstall pynput` along with updating pynput, but nothing has worked.

I am running KDE Plasma (Ubuntu LTS) and using Python 3.8.10.

EDIT: I have tried running the program on a Windows machine and it worked fine both in Pycharm and in PowerShell.

Comment: What if you use `pip3` and not `pip`?

Comment: Which OS are you using? In my case, with MacOS, I had to enable the keyboard access to the terminal and to python to be able to work with pynput.

Comment: @RandomDavis Looks the same, `pip3 install pynput` says pynput is already installed, pynput shows up in both terminals upon running `pip3 list`.

Comment: @SergioLema As stated in the post, I'm using KDE Plasma, which is built on Ubuntu LTS. I have read that MacOS had this problem, but I can't find any such setting in Konsole. I'll give it another look though.